# How to know which RestController is throwing a global exception?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

I have a Spring Boot application with multiple RestControllers, each of them connecting to different databases based on the services they are calling.

If any of them can't connect to the database for whatever reason, I'm throwing a message stating so like this:

```
@RestController
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    // The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    @ExceptionHandler(value = SQLRecoverableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleBaseException(Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body("Service Unavailable.");
    }

}
```

Now, is it possible to identify which RestController triggered this exception?

I don't know how to connect a Global Exception to a Rest Controller when I'm using @RestControllerAdvice

Comment: can you please add little bit of Controller code(in above question) from where Connection to DB is happening. May be we can add a check there itself and get our problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provide two level of Exception handling,

**1. Controller level.**
**2. Global level.**

Use controller level exception handling, If you need to add something based on controller basis.

Global level handling meant to be handle exception irrespective of knowing which controller exception belongs to.

Hope this answers your question. Better to go for controller level exception handing in your case.

Comment if you need more information.

Comment: I thought about going controller level, but if I have 30+ Controllers, I would be doing a catch of the same exception over and over again in every controller, duplicating code.

Comment: If all controller going to throw this exception then most likely global exception handler to be used. Any reason you need to controller name with exception ? if you need controller name must with exception then you have to go with each controller. if controller name is not needed then you go with global advice.

Comment: I'm trying to identify who is triggering the exception because I'm keeping a Log File per Service (which in this case, it is the same than saying a Log File per Controller). Having over 30 services, I would like to quickly identify which service is having issues connecting to the database and logging it accordingly so the alerts in place are fired.